# AngularJS : how to compare newValue with oldValue

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am using a window resize directive I found for Angular. it works great except for a multiple triggering issue. I am working with a map so I can not afford multiple redraws based on the map div height. The example is firing 3 times even though the values have not changed. I know I need to add a if statement newValue != oldValue to the watch but I am getting a too many digest cycles error. how do change this to work with the if statement?
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbjLh/506/)

```
app.directive('resize', function ($window) {
    return function (scope, element, attr) {

        var w = angular.element($window);
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return {
                'h': window.innerHeight, 
                'w': window.innerWidth
            };
        }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(newValue, oldValue);
            scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
            scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;

            scope.resizeWithOffset = function (offsetH) {
                scope.$eval(attr.notifier);
                return { 
                    'height': (newValue.h - offsetH) + 'px'                    
                };
            };

        }, true);

        w.bind('resize', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
});
```

UPDATE
how could I implement this?
[link](https://github.com/BaggersIO/angular.throttle)

Comment: You should consider using a throttle function on the window resize. That way it won't fire constantly.

Comment: how do i go about that

Comment: search for a [debounce](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) implementation

Comment: i have, all the examples are watching the ng-model-options for changes. I need to watch the directive window resize event

Comment: Sorry, http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/